# If state one already has a value I want to set state two instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick

I have a deck of cards with assigned numbers using dataset-keyMatch.
When I click on the first card I want it to assign the keyMatch value to the first state (choiceOne) and then when I click a second card I want to check that choiceOne has a value and if that is true I then assign choiceTwo the keyMatch value of the second card.

The card elements are imported from a MatchingCard Component.
Then the onClick event is assigned in the [classId] Component using the function handleChoice.

For choiceOne & choiceTwo

I tried with a default state of null

Then I tried with a default state of 0

```
 // -----------------Matching Card Game Functionality --------------------
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // States
  const [doubledDeck, setDoubledDeck] = useState([]);
  const [shuffledDeck, setShuffledDeck] = useState([]);
  const [deckReady, setDeckReady] = useState([]);
  const [matchingGameActive, setMatchingGameActive] = useState(false);

  const [turns, setTurns] = useState(0);
  const [choiceOne, setChoiceOne] = useState(0);
  const [choiceTwo, setChoiceTwo] = useState(0);

  // test the logic that I want for the onClick event on the MatchingCard
  // This works....so I don't know why it won't work when I click the cards

  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  const check = () => {
    choiceOne != 0 ? setChoiceTwo(random) : setChoiceOne(random);

    if (turns === 0) {
      setChoiceOne(random);
      setTurns((prevTurn) => prevTurn + 1);
    }

    if (turns === 1) {
      setChoiceTwo(random);
      setTurns(0);
    }
  };

  // Take the original double sided deck - split it - and combine into big deck for game

  const doubleTheDeck = (deck: any) => {
    const FlashcardsEnglish = deck.map((card: { props: { children: { props: any }[] } }) => {
      return card.props.children[0].props;
    });
    const FlashcardsJapanese = deck.map((card: { props: { children: { props: any }[] } }) => {
      return card.props.children[1].props;
    });

    const joinedDeck = FlashcardsEnglish.concat(FlashcardsJapanese);

    setDoubledDeck(joinedDeck);
  };

  // shuffle deck -----

  const shuffle = (deck: any[]) => {
    const shuffledCards = deck
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
      .map((card) => ({
        ...card,
      }));

    setShuffledDeck(shuffledCards);
  };

  // choice functionality
  const handleChoice = (e: { target: { dataset: { keyMatch: any } } }) => {
    const parsed = parseInt(e.target.dataset.keyMatch);
    // const str = e.target.dataset.keyMatch;
    // attempt #1 using "null" as the default state for choiceOne and Two
    // choiceOne ? setChoiceTwo(parsed) : setChoiceOne(parsed);

    // attempt #2 using 0 as the default state for choiceOne and Two
    if (turns === 0) {
      setChoiceOne(parsed);
      setTurns((prevTurn) => prevTurn + 1);
    }

    if (turns === 1) {
      setChoiceTwo(parsed);
      setTurns(0);
    }
  };
  console.log(choiceOne, choiceTwo);

  // create JSX elements------

  const finalDeck = shuffledDeck.map((card: { matchId: any; word: any }) => {
    const { matchId, word } = card;
    return (
      <MatchingCards key={matchId + word[0]} matchId={matchId} word={word} handleChoice={handleChoice}></MatchingCards>
    );
  });

  // prepare deck for game start -----

  const handleMatchingGameClick = () => {
    // take flahscards and double split them into two - doubling size
    doubleTheDeck(cardsForMatchingGame);
    //  shuffle the deck & sets the shuffledCards
    shuffle(doubledDeck);

    // create JSX elements from the new cards
    setDeckReady(finalDeck);
    // set game to active
    setMatchingGameActive((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  // useEffect(() => {}, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Header pageHeader={className} />
        <div className="bg-white">choice 1: {choiceOne}</div>
        <div className="bg-white">choice 2: {choiceTwo}</div>
        <button onClick={check}>check</button>
      </div>
      {/* <ToggleButton /> */}
      <div className="flex items-center  justify-between bg-slate-200 dark:bg-bd-1 p-4 ">
        <HomeButton />
        {/* <button onClick={handleMatchingGameClick}>start game</button> */}
        {/* <ShuffleButton onClick={shuffle(doubledDeck)} /> */}
        <MatchingGameButton
          content={matchingGameActive ? "Back to Regular Deck" : "Go to Matching Game"}
          onClick={handleMatchingGameClick}
        />
        <ToggleButton />
      </div>

      <div
        className="
        dark:bg-bd-1
        p-10
      bg-slate-200 gap-5 flex flex-col items-center justify-center
      sm:items-center sm:justify-center
      sm:grid
      sm:grid-cols-2
      md:grid 
      md:grid-cols-3 
      lg:grid-cols-4
       "
      >
        {matchingGameActive ? deckReady : cards};
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

What I return from the MatchingCards Component

```
 return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Header pageHeader={className} />
        <div className="bg-white">choice 1: {choiceOne}</div>
        <div className="bg-white">choice 2: {choiceTwo}</div>
        <button onClick={check}>check</button>
      </div>
      {/* <ToggleButton /> */}
      <div className="flex items-center  justify-between bg-slate-200 dark:bg-bd-1 p-4 ">
        <HomeButton />
        {/* <button onClick={handleMatchingGameClick}>start game</button> */}
        {/* <ShuffleButton onClick={shuffle(doubledDeck)} /> */}
        <MatchingGameButton
          content={matchingGameActive ? "Back to Regular Deck" : "Go to Matching Game"}
          onClick={handleMatchingGameClick}
        />
        <ToggleButton />
      </div>

      <div
        className="
        dark:bg-bd-1
        p-10
      bg-slate-200 gap-5 flex flex-col items-center justify-center
      sm:items-center sm:justify-center
      sm:grid
      sm:grid-cols-2
      md:grid 
      md:grid-cols-3 
      lg:grid-cols-4
       "
      >
        {matchingGameActive ? deckReady : cards};
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

When I click on a card my function only assigns choiceOne and then continues to reassign choiceOne. ChoiceTwo never gets given a value despite ChoiceOne already having a value.

I made a test function called "check" and the logic works there so I have no idea why it is not working on my card element.

Answer (score 0):

When a component renders MatchingCards Component is called leads to new state creation.